# AI platform online prediction with keras, custom preprocessing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I am new in deployment and I have few questions about the AI platform for online prediction. I am using Tensorflow 2.1 .
I trained my model with the keras API and use `tf.saved_model.save` function to save my model. Everything works fine, but I would like to include my preprocessing (tokenizer and padding) into the model (or at least being able to do it inside the "predict" function)

I know there is an option on google cloud ml engine called "custom prediction routine" which allow to do that on whatever framework we want, but the limit of a model is 500 mb. The model I am using is 1.5 gb and as I am using TF I wanted to keep the advantage to run a model of 2 gb as a limit size.

For now, what I am doing is :

Preprocessing the data -> do the request -> Model do the prediction and send the results -> get the results.

I would like to do :

Do the request on "raw data" -> Model do the preprocessing, do the prediction and send the results -> get the results

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Can you told me what was the solution you adopted ?? Somehow I'm facing a similar issue .

Answer (score 1):

You may not need a preprocessing container for this. Instead, write a custom serving function before exporting:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None], dtype=tf.string)])
def preproc_prediction(text):
  # preprocess
  text_str = text.numpy().decode('utf-8')
  text_str = preproc(text_str)

  # call model with preprocessed string
  text = tf.constant(text_str)
  pred = model(text, training=False)
  return {
    'preds': pred
  }

model.save(EXPORT_PATH, signatures={'serving_default': preproc_prediction})
```

Comment: Hi, I thank you for your answer.
 I need to convert the text (tf.string) into a string to do the preprocessing. Do you know if it is possible? I tried with .numpy() but It  does not seemµ to work.

Comment: that's because .numpy() gives you bytes.  you have to convert it into a string by decoding it. I've edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for you answer.  Sorry I was not clear. The numpy method seem to not exist with my tf.tensor string. I don't know why because outside of the function it works.

    convert_pytorch2TF.py:21 preproc_prediction  *
        text = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode(text.numpy(), max_length=MAX_LEN, pad_to_max_length=True))[None, :]

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'